# appendChild() alternative when used with documentFragment?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to build a section tag from the ground up using documentFragment(). It will include an h1 tag an article tag, which were initially being added with appendChild().  This section tag will also be cloned at some point and adjusted using cloneNode().

Then I found out that [appendChild() is buggy in IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917/en-us) along with articles from [Nick Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/03/17/the-dreaded-operation-aborted-error/), [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2011/surefire-dom-element-insertion/) and [Steve Souders](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/) quantifying how much appendChild sucks. I searched through S.O. for an alternative and using insertBefore and firstChild  seems to be the general consensus. As I want to insert nodes inside of other nodes, I'm not sure if insertBefore is an option here.

To be fair, this may not be the most efficient code. It's probably faster to code in the section tag with all the child nodes on the page then it is to script everything, then load it onto the page. And when I clone it, it will be easy to just find child nodes with firstChild and then adjust them. But before I do that, I just want to make sure that there's no other way to insert nodes inside of an element other than appendChild()?

Thanks in advance...kaidez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `appendChild()` so long as you don't try to use it on an element that is still being rendered by the browser. Wait until the `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` event fires on the document and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for responding! Just so I'm clear: it's okay to use appendChild() off-DOM in a document fragment and then load it on to the page? I read [the MDN spec on DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) and it looks like things will work since appendChild does stuff before the load event fires. I'm just asking because as far as IE goes, MDN also says that DomContentLoaded, is only supported on IE9. Thanks again!

Comment: @kaidez: Yes, you'll be fine using appendChild on a document fragment at any time (so long as you're appending newly created elements rather than existing ones from the page). It's true that `DOMContentLoaded` isn't supported in IE < 9, so you could just fall back to the `load` event.

Comment: You are, indeed, the man, sir!  I really do appreciate your help...thanks much!